# SQL retrieve data from parent type

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have several tables:

```
lecturer(id,name,email)
- 1,john,john@abc.com
- 2,andy,andy@abc.com
- 3,kyle,kyle@abc.com
- 4,allen,allen@abc.com

sig(id,name)
- s1, Multimedia
- s2, Business IT

expertise(id, description); 
- e1, Gaming
- e2, Graphic
- e3, Multimedia System
- e4, E-Business

lecturer_has_expertise(lecturer.id,expertise.id)
- 1, e1
- 2, e2
- 3, e4
- 4, e1

lecturer_has_sig (lecturer.id,sig.id)
- 1, s1
- 2, s1
- 3, s2

sig_has_expertise(sig.id,expertise.id)
- s1, e1
- s1, e2
- s1, e3
- s2, e4
```

Here is the output I want to show:

```
Lecturer's Name, Email, Expertise
```

Basically, when a user inputs a keyword eg: **Gaming** into the textbox, it will show which lecturer's expertise is gaming and since Gaming is under **Multimedia**,data about all lecturer in the **sig of Multimedia** also will be shown. For example:

```
Name   Email            Expertise
John   john@abc.com     Gaming
Allen  allen@abc.com    Gaming
Andy   andy@abc.com     Graphic
```

I manage to output only the expertise that is input by the user but not all the expertise in the same sig.

thanks in advance

Comment: What's `sig` short for, and can a lecturer have multiple of them?  What's the _modeled_ relationship between `sig` and `expertise`?  What have you tried so far?  Where do 'keywords' fit in?

Comment: sorry @X-Zero for not mention it earlier. sig is a special interest group which several lecturer is in the group and lecturer can reside in several group and they can have them more than one. the lecturer is grouped by their expertise in certain subject. so for one sig, there will be many expertise.

Comment: For example, i input keyword 'rfid' into the textbox.it will show the lecturer which has the expertise 'rfid' and i also want to show the lecturer with certain expertise in the same sig.

Comment: Is the `sig` made up of the expertises the lecturers have, or is it more 'this sig will be about RFID, but we don't have a lecturer'?  Define 'certain expertise in the same sig' - do you want some sort of related field, all lecturers with RFID expertise, all lecturers in the same sig as a lecturer with RFID expertise, or what?

Comment: Can there be more than one lecturer with the same expertise? If so, can those lecturers belong to different SIGs? If so, would you need to return all the lecturers in all those SIGs?

Comment: @AndriyM yes, yes and yes. one lecturer can be in two SIGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to return every teacher who either

- has the specified expertise

  or
- belongs to a group that has the specified expertise.

This is how the above translates in SQL:

```
SELECT
  l.name,
  l.email,
  e.description AS expertise
FROM lecturer_has_expertise le
  INNER JOIN lecturer l ON l.id = le.lecturer_id
  INNER JOIN expertise e ON e.id = le.expertise_id
WHERE e.description = @InputExpertise
   OR EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM lecturer_has_sig ls
       INNER JOIN sig_has_expertise se ON ls.sig_id = se.sig_id
       INNER JOIN expertise e ON e.id = se.expertise_id
     WHERE e.description = @InputExpertise
       AND ls.lecturer_id = le.lecturer_id
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

This works (at least for your sample) and tested it on MySQL. But it's plain SQL so it should work on most databases.

```
SELECT lc.name, lc.email, ex.description
FROM lecturer lc 
INNER JOIN lecturer_has_expertise lhc ON lc.id = lhc.lcId
INNER JOIN expertise ex ON ex.id = lhc.exId
WHERE ex.description = 'Gaming'

UNION

SELECT lc.name, lc.email, ex2.description
FROM 
(SELECT she.sigId FROM expertise ex 
INNER JOIN sig_has_expertise she ON she.exId = ex.id
WHERE ex.description = 'Gaming') sigex
INNER JOIN sig_has_expertise she2 ON sigex.sigId = she2.sigId
INNER JOIN expertise ex2 ON she2.exId = ex2.id
INNER JOIN lecturer_has_expertise lhc ON ex2.id = lhc.exId
INNER JOIN lecturer lc ON lhc.lcId = lc.id
```

Next time please provide DDLs for sample data (at least for such complex queries).

Comment: sorry but the code above return an error as there is no she.sig_id in the expertise table.

Comment: That's why I've written "Next time please provide DDLs for sample data". From your examples I can't see how your columns are named in the relation tables. And `she` is the alias for the `sig_has_expertise` table.

Comment: i'm sorry for the inconvenience caused but can you tell me what (SELECT she.sigId FROM expertise ex 
INNER JOIN sig_has_expertise she ON she.exId = ex.id
WHERE ex.description = 'Gaming) does in plain english? Does it select expertise id for gaming?

Comment: It selects all sigs that have expertise "Gaming". The next `JOIN` is getting all expertises for the found sigs, then join to expertises itself so we can get the details for the result, and join further with lecturers to get lecturer details.